# Why does awk fail when part of ssh command?

Tags: bash, awk, ssh

When I ssh into a server and run the command, it works:

```
$ssh -q postgres@XXXXX
Last login: Mon Mar 12 12:30:16 2018 from 10.101.XXX.X
[postgres@pgsdba203 ~]$ df -hP | grep pgsql | awk '{ if ($5 >= 70) print $0 }'
/dev/mapper/pgvg-pg_log  9.9G  7.2G  2.2G  77% /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log
```

But not when it's part of an ssh command parameter:

```
$ ssh -q postgres@XXXXX "df -hP | grep pgsql | awk '{ if ($5 >= 70) print $0 }'"
awk: { if ( >= 70) print -bash }
awk:        ^ syntax error
```

Since the awk command is in single quotes, I'd have expected the `$5` to be preserved and passed directly to server XXXXX.

EDIT: the end goal is to make the server name into a variable and call ssh from within a bash for loop.

Comment: It's not in single quotes, though; the `'` are just characters in a double-quoted string, so `$5` is expanded before the string is even passed to the remote shell.

Comment: BTW -- when you're asking a question similar to many others already in the knowledgebase, it's useful to call out the near-duplicates and show how you tried to apply the advice in each and how those attempts failed. (Though as some of the duplicates include the answer you're getting from Gilles, presumably some of those attempts *wouldn't* have failed in fact).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when typing in the subject, I looked at the existing questions that SO automatically suggested, but did not see anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do :

```
ssh -q postgres@XXXXX <<'EOF'
df -hP | awk '/pgsql/ && $5 >= 70'
EOF
```

or in a *for loop*

```
for server in foo bar base; do
    ssh -q postgres@$server <<'EOF'
    df -hP | awk '/pgsql/ && $5 >= 70'
EOF
done
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is that feasible within a for loop?

Comment: Check my edited post

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you have error, report it

Comment: I was doing that just as you made that comment...  :)

Comment: Tested, work well

Comment: Works well, *except* when you need to pass data over stdin and thus need to have it available for code. Which, granted, isn't the OP's immediate case here.

Comment: I still was using `-n`.  Took that out and it works.

Answer (score 0):

As an easy-to-define pattern, which works even when you need to pipe stdin into your remote code: Define a shell function, and *tell the shell itself* to emit that function's literal text substituted into the remote command:

```
myfunc() { df -hP | grep pgsql | awk '{ if ($5 >= 70) print $0 }'; }
ssh -q postgres@XXXX "$(declare -f myfunc); myfunc"
```